# DB2 reporting incorrect filesystem full error?

Tags: linux, db2, db2-luw

DB2 V10.5, RHEL 7.5

We had an issue when DB2 was stuck not being able to write log files to disk because of disk full error  just that there was more than enough free disk space on the filesystem that DB2 uses.

For example, we have the folowing filesystem structure:

```
/a     
/a/b    DB1 database
/a/b/c  DB1 diagnostics logs
/a/b/d  DB1 transaction logs
/a/b/e  DB1 archived logs
```

I had DIA8312C Disk was full  Error (OS) for filesystem /a together with OSERR: ENOSPC (28) and also DIA8312C Disk was full Severe level and many more errors , because filesystem /a was full.

Is this normal, considering that all filesystems that DB2 uses ( /a/b, /a/b/c, a/b/d/..) had enough free space ?

Comment: db2 doesn't calculate any free space itself. It got an error from the corresponding OS call probably. Check ulimit / disk quotas for the db2 instance owner.

Comment: Which logs exactly are you talking about? Diagnostic logs? Transaction logs? Are all the directories you show different mount points of different file systems? What else is using the file system in question?

Comment: both of them, they have separate filesystems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the OS was rebooted without shutting down the database and during shutdown process, after some filesystems were unmounted , the database dumped some errors on the same path were one of the filesystems was mounted. 
After server came up, the filesystem was automatically mounted on top of those files dumped by db2 thus they couldn't be seen.

Comment: +1 for reporting back the solution.